# Sort with results matching condition on top

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, php-mongodb

I have written mongodb aggregation query in php like below lines of code.

```
         $orrollno= array('$or' => array(array("student.roll_no" => new MongoRegex("/$arg/i"))));

            $orlastname= array('$or' => array(array("student.last_name" => new MongoRegex("/$arg/i"))));

            $oremail= array('$or' => array(array("student.email" => new MongoRegex("/$arg/i"))));

            $orguardian= array('$or' => array(array("student.guardian_name" => new MongoRegex("/$arg/i"))));

            $orphone= array('$or' => array(array("student.phone1" => new MongoRegex("/$arg/i"))));

            $orfullname= array('$or' => array(array("fullname" => new MongoRegex("/$arg/i"))));

            $orfirstmiddle= array('$or' => array(array("firstmiddle" => new MongoRegex("/$arg/i"))));

            $orfirstlast= array('$or' => array(array("firstlast" => new MongoRegex("/$arg/i"))));

            $query = array( '$or' => array($orrollno,$orlastname,$oremail,$orguardian,$orphone,$orfullname,$orfirstmiddle,$orfirstlast));


         $outputTotalResults= $this->db->studentTbl->aggregate(
          array(
                 array(
                    '$project' => array(
                      'fullname' => array('$concat' => array('$first_name',  ' ',  '$middle_name', ' ', '$last_name')),
                      'firstmiddle' => array('$concat' => array('$first_name',  ' ',  '$middle_name')),
                      'firstlast' => array('$concat' => array('$first_name',  ' ',  '$last_name')),
                      'student' => '$$ROOT'
                       )
                ),
                  array(
                      '$match' => $query
                       ),
                    )
                 );
```

I am trying to sort the results which comes from $match => $query. 
For e.g $arg contains "William David" then results should first contain the records with names Willian David and then the rest of the results.

Any help shall be greatly appreciated!!!

Based on ur suggestion I have now tried the below

```
            $outputTotalResults= $this->db->studentTbl->aggregate(
          array(
                 array(
                    '$project' => array(
                      'fullname' => array('$concat' => array('$first_name',  ' ',  '$middle_name', ' ', '$last_name')),
                      'firstmiddle' => array('$concat' => array('$first_name',  ' ',  '$middle_name')),
                      'firstlast' => array('$concat' => array('$first_name',  ' ',  '$last_name')),
                      'student' => '$$ROOT',
                       'weight' => array(
                          '$cond' => array(
                                       array( 
                                         '$or' => array( 
                                          array('$eq' => array('$fullname' => $arg )),
                                          array('$eq' => array('$firstmiddle' => $arg)),
                                          array('$eq' => array('$firstlast' => $arg)),
                                          )
                                        ),
                                       10,
                                        0
                                      )
                                   ),
                        array(
                             '$sort' => array( 'weight'=> -1 )
                              ),
                        array(
                             '$match' => $query
                             ),
                         )
                      )
                   )
               );
```

Comment: I think you are doing completely the wrong operation here. Forgetting your code entirely, then is is actually your intention to "float" results for "Willam" in `first_name` and "David" in `last_name` to the "top" of your results, with any other results after that? If so then there is a way to do that, but `$group` is not the operator to get that done.

Comment: which  operator is suitable for doing this requirement. I am very new to mongodb... Please help

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve here is a "weighted sort", where you essentially want to calculate a field based on conditions and then apply a [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) pipeline stage to that result.

The general case is to apply [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) with a logical condition and either return a value or not, possibly for more than one condition in a cascading way.

Ideally with MongoDB 3.4 and above, use [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/):

```
array(
  array(
    '$addFields' => array(
      'weight' => array(
        '$cond => array(
          array( 
            '$and' => array( 
              array( '$eq' => array( '$first_name', 'Willam' ) )
              array( '$eq' => array( '$last_name', 'David' ) )
            )
          ),
          10,
          0
        )
      )
    )
  ),
  array(
    '$sort' => array( 'weight'=> -1 )
  )
)
```

Or in prior versions where you cannot simply "append" a new field to the existing document structure you use [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/), either specifying each field you want or altering the structure returning under one property via `$$ROOT`:

```
array(
  array(
    '$project' => array(
      'first_name' => 1,
      'last_name' => 1,
      'weight' => array(
        '$cond => array(
          array( 
            '$and' => array( 
              array( '$eq' => array( '$first_name', 'Willam' ) )
              array( '$eq' => array( '$last_name', 'David' ) )
            )
          ),
          10,
          0
        )
      )
    )
  ),
  array(
    '$sort' => array( 'weight'=> -1 )
  )
)
```

So in that simple case, whenever the "both" conditions (via [`$and`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/and/)) are met, the `weight` property is assigned a value of `10`, otherwise it gets a `0`. The subsequent sort on the `weight` property is in "descending" order, so all the `10` values where the condition matched will be on "top", whilst all other results will come after all the matches.

---

This is how you would structure for your exact implementation. First you `$match` your query conditions as this reduces the overall documents to process and this is the **only** time an aggregation pipeline can actually use an index.

Then you `$project` the field with the comparisons for whether the match phrase was in the preferred fields, and finally `$sort` on that calculated field.

```
array(
  array( '$match' => $query ),
  array(
    '$addFields' => array(
      'weight' => array(
        '$cond => array(
          array( 
            '$or' => array( 
              array( 
                '$eq' => array( 
                  array('$concat' => array('$first_name',  ' ',  '$middle_name', ' ', '$last_name')),
                  $arg
                )
              ),
              array( 
                '$eq' => array(
                  array('$concat' => array('$first_name',  ' ',  '$middle_name')), 
                  $arg 
                )
              ),
              array(
                '$eq' => array(
                  array('$concat' => array('$first_name',  ' ',  '$last_name')),
                  $arg 
                )
              )
            )
          ),
          10,
          0
        )
      )
    )
  ),
  array(
    '$sort' => array( 'weight'=> -1 )
  )
)
```

So **always** `$match` first or otherwise use a pipeline stage that is going to use an index and "optimize" your result. Then manipulate and remember that you cannot use calculated fields for comparison in a "single" `$project` phase. If you really need it then you either duplicate the calculations or do the calculations in one stage and then compare on the values in the next stage.

Honestly though, once you go to these lengths you are basically reproducing what a [text search](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/text-search/), in which you can:

1. Spread the index across all the fields you want to search in. This eliminates the massive `$or` condition into a simple query operation.
2. Specify a weighting on the particular fields where the match would be more important.

The only case where a "text search" would not be the best solution is if the fields you want "more weight on" change on a regular basis. Since text indexes have "set" values for the weighting and you can have only **one** per collection, then you cannot easily change the combination of fields to assign more weight to. With the aggregation process shown, its fairly trivial to change around the fields and assignment of weight.

Comment: our requirements are $arg might contain full name (first +middle+last) or  combination first and middle name or even first and last name. and i cannot separate name fields into two separate arrays and perform "and" operation on them. That is why i have concatenated them in $project.. There are so many other conditions in $query variable. My code works fine but it does not fetch the nearer results first. Also I am not allowed to add feilds in database... please alter the above solution

Comment: @user2179026 Your code does not work because `$group` does not do what you seem to think it does. All I am demonstrating here is placing the "weight" on the condition where the first name matches a given argument and the second matches a given argument. You can just as easily make the condition a test of various concatenation combinations against a given string and apply weight accordingly. Again not helped by your attempt being so far off the mark.

Comment: I have updated my actual code which is working and is without group

Comment: @user2179026 So looking at your edit you are looking to match documents that contain a value in one of many possible fields right. But what you want to do is put the ones where the combination of certain fields matches the value. Which means just replace the condition in `$cond` with whatever expression constructs the string to match the balancing argument.

Comment: @user2179026 And for the third time. That is because `$group` has nothing to do with this. If you want "weights" then your `$project` them by condition as demonstrated.

Comment: i will implement the same on my actual and let u know if that will work

Comment: It throws error message:  invalid operator '$fullname'' Please help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144535/discussion-between-user2179026-and-neil-lunn).

Comment: @user2179026 You seem to have struggled with the implementation. Whilst I don't stay on here all day, I've included the listing matching what you are trying to achieve and some further notes you should consider.